# Javascript keeps hiding my web background

Tags: javascript, html, css

My webpage loads with the background, then I click on the link and it gives me my javascript like anticipated, but once it finishes and outputs the results, it goes to a blank white screen with my results. I want the results to be displayed on my webpage with the background. I have tried and tried with no avail. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{

var accountnum;
var beginningBal;
var itemsCharged;
var credits;
var creditLimit;
var sum;

accountnum = window.prompt("Enter the account number:");

beginningBal = window.prompt("Enter the beginning balance:");

itemsCharged = window.prompt("Total of all items charged:");

credits = window.prompt("Total credits applied to this account:");

creditLimit = window.prompt("Enter the credit limit: ");

var zero = parseInt (accountnum);
var first = parseInt(beginningBal);
var second = parseInt(itemsCharged);
var third = parseInt (credits);
var fourth = parseInt (creditLimit);
var sum = first + second - third;
var diff = fourth - sum;
if (sum < fourth)
{
    document.writeln("<h1>Your account number is:" + zero);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your beginning balance is: $" + first);
    document.writeln("<h1>Total of items charged: $" + second);
    document.writeln("<h1>Total credits applies to this account: $" + third);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your credit limit is: $" + fourth);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your account balance is: $" + sum);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your credit is: $" + diff);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;

}
else if (sum > fourth)
{
    document.writeln("<h1>Your account number is:" + zero);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your beginning balance is: $" + first);
    document.writeln("<h1>Total of items charged: $" + second);
    document.writeln("<h1>Total credits applies to this account: $" + third);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your new account balance is: $" + sum);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your credit limit is: $" + fourth);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your new balance is: $" + diff);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your credit is exceeded!");
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
}
else if (sum == fourth)
{
    document.writeln("<h1>Your account number is:" + zero);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your beginning balance is: $" + first);
    document.writeln("<h1>Total of items charged: $" + second);
    document.writeln("<h1>Total credits applies to this account: $" + third);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your account balance is: $" + sum);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your credit limit is: $" + fourth);
    document.writeln("<h1>Your new balance is: $" + diff);
    document.writeln("<h1>You are out of credit!");
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
}
}

</script>
<style>
#output{
    height:43px;

}
html{
     background: url(images/nxerainbowgrid.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
     z-index:-9999; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/nxerainbowgrid.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/nxerainbowgrid.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction()"><p>CLICK HERE TO HAVE FUN!!!</p></a>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A JSfiddle will be useful for us

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not the best way. or the right way. You should not repeat a lot of code. and use prompt. The following could be a temporary solution

define html and also change the ccs style to body. in that case. background image will be aplly to the body of the page

```
 var html;
 if(sum<forth){
    html ="<h1> Your account number is:" + zero + "</h1>";
    html ="<h1>Your beginning balance is: $" + first + "</h1>";
    html ="<h1>Total of items charged: $" + second + "</h1>";
    html ="<h1>Total credits applies to this account: $" + third + "</h1>";
    html ="<h1>Your credit limit is: $" + fourth + "</h1>";
    html ="<h1>Your account balance is: $" + sum + "</h1>";
    html ="<h1>Your credit is: $" + diff + "</h1>";
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
}    


 body{
    background: url(index.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    /*keep all other. only change the tag name*/
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. give me a minute.

Comment: Ok maybe I am not understanding you put: document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<h1> My Dom </h1>"; I am not understanding what you mean by <h1> My Dom </h1>

Comment: Do you have a input set. for each steps. I am putting the number and seeing the result. In your case are you seeing the background image.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? If so you can see that the thing appears to work fine you click on the link then it pops up the javascript and asks the questions. Then once it is done it it outputs the results, however when it outputs the results my webpage background disappears and I get a white screen with my results. I want it to simply output the results on the webpage with the background.

Comment: Declare a html variable before if else.
you need to apply background image to the body of the website or div. 
and write innerHtml to the div. 

If this solves your issue, accept the answer

Comment: It appears that doing what you said worked but only for the line right above:  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;    It does output that line right above it onto the web background, however the rest of the lines above that line are not there.

Comment: Still no luck with this question!

Comment: I didnt get it. Did replaced css selector to "body"? 
you have to change all the if else block, the way i have mentioned for the first if-else block. 

If it doesn't work. let me know